# Help with reformulating linear programming with rounding numbers

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, programming

I have the following problem, abstracting away a few details from a real-world application, that I want to solve with linear programming (or any other mathematical optimization with constraints, really).

I have two sets of values $y$ and $\hat{r}$. $y$ are real-world measured values, while $\hat{r}$ are outputs from a simulation with mathematical model. $y$ are integers in range $[0, 1, \dots, 21]$, while $\hat{r}$ are real numbers in range $[0, 21]$ that are rounded to integers $\hat{y}$. So far I used regular rounding, e.g. $1.33 \rightarrow 1$, $2.5 \rightarrow 3$, $21.0 \rightarrow 21$. This can also be written as $\text{round}(x) = \lfloor x+0.5 \rfloor$.

My $y$ values distribution is far from uniform (more like log-normal), which is reflected by the model, which often outputs values too large (for small $y$) or too small (for large $y$). My idea is to "optimize" the rounding, changing the range $[a_i, a_{i+1}]$ for which the number is rounded to $i$. I minimize the sum of absolute deviations, i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^n |y_j - \hat{y}_j|$ (for $n$ observations). For each $\hat{r}_j$, I have $\hat{y}_j = \min_{i} \left|\hat{r}_j - \frac{a_{i+1} - a_i}{2}\right|$, i.e. I find the range $[a_i, a_{i+1}]$ for which the center is the closest to $\hat{r}_j$.

Additionally, for thresholds $a_i$ I have constraints $a_0 = 0$, $a_{21} = 21$, and $a_i < a_{i+1}$ for all $i = 0, 1, \dots, 20$.

My formulation so far is:

$$
\text{minimize } \sum_{j=1}^n \left|y_j - \hat{y}_j\right| \\
\text{for variables } a_i, i = 0, 1, \dots, 21 \\
\text{where } \hat{y}_j = \arg \min_{i} \left|\hat{r}_j - \frac{a_{i+1} - a_i}{2}\right| \\
\text{subject to:} \\
a_0 = 0 \\
a_{21} = 21 \\
a_i < a_{i+1}, i = 0, 1, \dots, 20
$$

The problem lies in formulation of $\hat{y}_j$, which is a nonlinear function. I know that this could be optimized with any blackbox zero-order optimizer, but I am pretty sure this can be reformulated to use linear programming efficiently.

I also had an idea to directly optimize $\sum_{j=1}^n \left|\hat{r}_j - \frac{a_{i+1} - a_i}{2}\right|$, make it an integer and use MIP (Mixed Integer Programming), but I'm not sure if that would be an equivalent formulation.

Example data, for simpler case with $j=4$:

```
y,r
0,0.1
0,0.3
1,0.45
1,0.49
1,0.65
1,0.67
1,0.78
1,0.99
1,1.1
1,1.27
1,1.7
2,1.9
2,2.1
3,3.3
3,3.4
4,3.5
4,3.99
```

With regular rounding, i.e. $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 0.5$, $a_2 = 1.5$, $a_3 = 2.5$, $a_4 = 3.5$, $a_5 = 4$, I get `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]`, with sum of absolute deviations 3.

However, predictions here are heavily skewed towards 1. For thresholds $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 0.4$, $a_2 = 1.75$, $a_3 = 2.5$, $a_4 = 3.5$, $a_5 = 4$, I get `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]` and sum of absolute deviations 0.

Comment: I think your formulation may not do what you expect, if $a_1-a_0 <a_2-a_1$, then a number slightly above $a_1$ will be rounded to $0$ instead of $1$.

Comment: You can model with a MILP by using decision variables for each interval but I doubt you can handle this with LP. This seems quite close to piecewise constant fitting, you can look at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0167637788900302.

Comment: @caduk you are right, my assignment is wrong. Every range $[a_i, a_{i+1}]$ contains a natural number $i$, which is my $\hat{y}$, target natural number. I want measurements $r$ in that range to get rounded to that $\hat{y}$. Do you have an idea how to fix that notation?

Also, using MILP is 100% ok for me, problem is not that large anyway. The piecewise constant fitting looks interesting, but I don't have a function here, just measurements on 1-dimensional axis. The only information really is their density, in particular around natural numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem via linear programming by reformulating as a shortest path problem in a layered network defined as follows.  Let $R$ be the set of distinct $r$ values.  Let $I=\{1,\dots,4\}$.  The main nodes are $R \times I$, and the main arcs are from $(r,i)$ to $(r',i+1)$, where $r<r'$.  The idea is that arc $(r,i)\to(r',i+1)$ is traversed if all observations with $r \le r_j < r'$ have $\hat{y}_j=i$.  The cost for traversing the arc is the sum of absolute deviations
$$\sum_{j: r \le r_j < r'} \left|y_j - i\right|.$$
Add a source node $(0,0)$, with directed arcs to all $(r,1)$, and a sink node $(4,5)$, with directed arcs from all $(r,4)$.  Now find a shortest path from source to sink.  For each arc $(r,i)\to(r',i+1)$ that appears in the shortest path, take $a_i=r$.

Comment: An interesting idea. I drew a part of that graph: https://t.ly/5O5ke. I hope I understood the idea correctly. But this enforces the thresholds to be measurements, right? Coming back to my example data, setting a_2 = 1.75 would be impossible, since it's not one of measured r values. This may not be a problem, but I want to make sure I understand correctly

Comment: Very clever. @qalis, you can use as a threshold any value between two measurements where there is a jump.

Comment: @qalis Your drawing is almost correct, but you drew the source node $(0.1,0)$ twice. You can also omit the other nodes with $i=0$ if you want. They will not be used in a path from the source.

Comment: @RobPratt thanks! I fixed the graph, I will post it as a separate answer in case someone needs this in the future. I will implement this, and compare to blackbox optimization, I think the results will be pretty interesting.

Comment: Glad to help.  I guess to be consistent with your specification that $a_0=0$, we should make the source node $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

An example graph from excellent answer by @RobPratt. It uses some of the sample data I provided in the original question, and I drew just a subset of edges for clarity. Edges here are weighted, as per Rob's answer, with sums of absolute deviations with a given rounding, and they are also directed (from "left" to "right").

Edit: fix left node to be always $(0, 0)$.

[image: graph]